# Erro apos atualizar o Android Studio para versão 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, acabei de atualizar minha versão de 2.1 para 3.0.1 e esta aparecendo esse erro

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar] Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details Information:BUILD FAILED in 44s Information:2 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in console

Não está aparecendo a tela do smartphone do activity_main.xml que montamos a interface dos apps

Comment: Eu focaria na parte que diz *"check logs for details"*, e talvez em *"See complete output in console"*.

Answer (score 1):

Com a versão 3.0 do AndoridStudio, temos o [AAPT2](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html) habilitado por padrão em todos os projetos.

Esse problema acontece em alguns projetos anteriores ao AS 3.0 quando o Manifesto do aplicativo não está corretamente estruturado. O AAPT2 obriga que o manifesto siga uma estrutura padrão.

Então, verifique o AndroidManifest.xml do seu aplicativo e tente corrigi-lo. Você também pode consultar esse guia da [estrutura do arquivo do manifesto](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct).

Basicamente, ele deve seguir essa estrutura *(nem todas as TAGs são obrigatórias)*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>

    <uses-permission />
    <permission />
    <permission-tree />
    <permission-group />
    <instrumentation />
    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-configuration />  
    <uses-feature />  
    <supports-screens />  
    <compatible-screens />  
    <supports-gl-texture />  

    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action />
                <category />
                <data />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity-alias>

        <service>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
        </service>

        <receiver>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission />
            <meta-data />
            <path-permission />
        </provider>

        <uses-library />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Se mesmo assim não funcionar, você pode desabilitar o AAPT2 no **gradle.properties** adicionando/alterando a linha:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado ao adicionar o código android.enableAapt2=false funcionou

Comment: Fico feliz em saber que pude ajudar. Mas gostaria de reforçar que essa solução não resolve o problema, apenas o esconde. Recomendo que você procure saber mais sobre o AAPT2 e tente corrigir definitivamente essa falha.